# C++ Two functions in while loop condition

Tags: c++, while-loop

So I have a while loop like this:

```
while ( (ret1 == funct1 () ) == 0 && (ret2 == funct2 () ) != 1)
{
    // do nothing
}
```

Will both functions be called at the same time?  Like running two threads?  Thanks.

Comment: ***Will both functions be called at the same time? Like running two threads?*** No both functions will not be executed at the same time. funct1() will execute and if the result of `(ret1 == funct1 () ) == 0 ` is true funct2() will execute.

Comment: OK, then after conditon 2 returns true, it does nothing in the while loop, then rechecks the two conditions again (ret1, then ret2).  I think I understand now.  Thank you